# Объявлять ли новогодний конкурс для 2023 года?

Tags: обсуждение, конкурс

В прошлом году с подачи Harry мною был объявлен вот такой [новогодний конкурс](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1367394/228791) на представление числа 2022 разными арифметическими способами.

Я подумывал объявить его и в этом году, но Harry уже выдал [вот такой ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1478703/228791), после которого я не знаю, есть ли какой-то смысл в таком конкурсе?

Как вы считаете, надо объявлять конкурс для 2023 года или нет?

Comment: Ну можно что-то новое придумать)

Comment: @Qwertiy Т.е. нет? Что-то другое мне придумывать просто лень :) Или недостаток воображения.

Comment: Я не знаю... Просто предложил)

Comment: @Qwertiy Ну, раз никто не кричит "без этого жить не могу" — то, как говорится, "Леди из Кадиллака..." :)

Comment: Ну я новогодний конкурс хочу)

Comment: @Qwertiy Этот же? На арифметику? И что тогда делать с Harry, который дал ответ до конкурса?

Comment: Любой интересный. Лучше на программирование)

Comment: Давайте исключим из условия операцию факториал и добавим битовые операции. Типа `console.log(9<<999|999)`. Будет интереснее.

Comment: @DiD Это хорошая идея - битовый конкурс! Так и сделал (только убрал еще и умножения и прочее - чтоб наработками Harry нельзя было воспользоваться).